# Get data from the last week SQL & Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am currently working on a web application and using ChartJS. I need to get data from the last 7 days and count it. I explain:

I need to count the number of client that registered each days from the seven last days to display it with ChartJS.

I have some problems with the SQL Request.

**Get today's date:**

```
$jj = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
```

In my database, i have a **'created_at'** column with timestamp like this :

```
2018-08-21 11:07:59
```

For the request, I followed some tutorials and did this:

```
SELECT count(client.id) FROM parcel WHERE created_at = :dateclient, array('dateclient' => $jj);
```

But the request isn't working, I assume that there are some errors. If some pros knows how to do it !

*By the way: I did the request for one date for the moment, but I will need to do it for seven days*

Comment: So where are you setting the date back seven days?

Comment: Try this :: `$jj = (new DateTime('now -7 days'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my explication, but the problem isn't with going back 7 days (in my shared code, I try with today's date). But how to do my SQL request (compare datetime in the column **created_at** and actual date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use eloquent query to overcome SQL Injection like following

Here I am assuming you have Models folder inside App folder else you can directly use **Parcel::** without **Models\Parcel**

```
$lastWeek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 day", date('Y-m-d')));
/* In the following code you can directly get the count value */
$parcelCount  = Models\Parcel::whereDate('created_at', $lastWeek)->count();
```

OR using **DB::raw**

```
$parcelCount = Models\Parcel::select(\DB::raw("COUNT(id) as parcel_count"))
    ->whereDate('created_at', $lastWeek)
    ->first();
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response ! But when I try your code, i got the following error: **A non well formed numeric value encountered** at the line with the **$lastWeek = date(...);**

Comment: Finally it worked when I used my variable **$jj** with your $parcelCount. Thank you for the response and the tip !